# How to make columns from 2 templates shifting correctly?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I am a beginner in PowerQuery language and I'm trying to solve this problem.

The Problem has 2 templates with 22 columns from application output of data with a difference. One of them has a hidden column that PowerQuery counts, shifting the content that I have to elaborate.

I try to explain myself with an example

```
Col 1          Col 2        Col 3
Status1        IP1          xxxx
Status2        IP2          xxxx
Status3        IP3          xxxx
null           Status1      IP1
null           Status2      IP2
null           Status3      IP3
```

and so on.

I cannot find criteria to make it shift in the correct way and have the same value in the same column.

Last Column(22) has a null value for the first output and a value in the second.

So I tried that:

```
if (each[Column22]=null) then Table.ReplaceValue(#"XXX", each[Column2], 
    each[Column1],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1"})
```

I think after that to iterate this formula for all columns.

This isn't working.

Could you please help me?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: So the top 3 rows and bottom 3 rows come from different sources? Can you not just remove the extra column before appending the tables?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem is that I don't know how many files I received to feed the source. I cannot know in advance which template have this extra column!

Comment: I thought the same of you anyway as fast solution..  :(

Comment: Do the columns have any kind of naming that you can work with?